# Create PHP session for all users or only ones who want to log in?

Tags: php, session

At the moment my CMS creates a PHP session for every user who visits the site. I'm thinking about only creating a session for users who want to log in. The problem I have here is that some UI elements for logged in users are on all pages, so on every page request the system has to check if the user is logged in, which means I have no other option to start a session on every page request? Or am I wrong? Is it normal practise to create a session for every user, even if dose not want to log in?

Short, I'd like to know if A. there is an option in my use case to only create a PHP session for users who want to log in and B. if it consider bad practise creating a session for every user, regardless if he wants to log in or not. If this isn't the case, I can leave things as they are really ...

Comment: Sessions are not a bad thing unless your trying to store gigabytes of data in your session variable (and i have seen sites out there that post megs of data back and fourth in session parameters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no (real) choice. You can not know, that a user is logged in (or not) without a session.

Comment: So I was right in the first place, as you said, in my use case I don't have a other option anyway? Still, I am interested to know what if this is in general consider "bad practise" or not.

Comment: I think that's about all I wanted to know, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer:

In your use case, it is perfectly fine to create a session for every user. Sessions are negligible and not something to worry about as far as performance goes (in your case).

The method you're using is not bad practice at all. In fact I'd say it's pretty near best practice.

Long answer:
In my 6+ years of experience as a PHP programmer in the corporate world, it is perfectly normal to create a session for every user, regardless of whether or not they're logged in. In fact, sessions can be used to do a lot of convenient features for a user even when they're not logged in -- such as shopping carts, etc. You're doing things right. If you want to speed up performance at all, use a tool like Google's Pagespeed and Yahoo's YSlow -- they'll give you tips on best practice for websites.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! Really helpful. What a pity that one can't mark multiple answers as correct, so much good stuff here!

Answer (score 2):

It *is* possible to avoid creating a session every time.  So what if session files are small?  Why proliferate them when it's unnecessary?

This is what I do, in essence:

Check for the existence of the session cookie on the incoming request, and only do the `session_start()` if you've received one.

Logged-out users browsing the site (typically) won't be sending the session cookie, and so they won't trigger a `session_start()`.  Simple.

Once someone logs into your site and you do want to start a session (session both logically in your application and in the PHP sense) then use `session_start()` etc which will handle setting up the cookie.

And once someone logs out, make sure you destroy the session cookie too, not just the PHP session itself.

Obviously the user could block your cookie operations at their end and screw things up, but they could do this anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just look for an empty $_SESSION value to see if they're logged in?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if I don't start the session (thing I wanted to avoid for all users who don't want to log in, e.g. regular visitors) the $_SESSION will always be non-existent, so that's not a real option.

Comment: So check if $_SESSION exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, logins are managed via the session, therefore you must create a session at the start of the page to determine if they are logged in or not. You have no choice really... It is not bad practise, it is common practise.